# How to iterate over c++ vector and operate on two values at a time using the range-v3 library?

Tags: c++, range-v3

Let's say I have a vector of numbers:

```cpp
std::vector< int > v{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

I want to iterate over the vector and operate on two at a time; that is, I want to operate on:

- `(1,2)`,
- `(2,3)`, and
- `(3,4)`.

I know there is a way to do this using Eric Neibler's [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library (slated to be in C++20), but I can't remember the exact sequence of commands.

---

I could do this using iterators

```cpp
for( auto begin = v.begin(); begin != (v.end()-1); begin++ ){
  // Do something with *begin and *(begin+1)
}
```

Using the range-v3 library would make this so much more elegant and readable. I just can't remember what the command is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Way to Use C++ 11's for-range Syntax for Sequential Pairs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273606/way-to-use-c-11s-for-range-syntax-for-sequential-pairs)

Comment: @Mureinik That would do the trick, but much more complicated than the iterator example I posted (and then updated).

Comment: I think the ranges-v3 term you're looking for is `sliding`

Comment: @chris Yes `sliding` is the term. Turn this into an answer and I'll give you credit for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eric Niebler's library, this is known as a sliding view ([live example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Ng66gJ)):

```
using namespace ranges;
std::vector< int > v{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };

for (const auto& p : v | views::sliding(2)) {
    std::cout << p[0] << ' ' << p[1] << '\n';
}
```

I don't think this particular view is included in C++20 out of the box, but I believe there's a fair chance of it appearing in the future. Unfortunately, `zip_view` [had to be cut from P1035](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/26), so the "canonical" implementation via `zip` (zipping the range with itself minus the first element) will probably be a bit more involved as well.